# В чем разница между QPushButton и QPushButtonPrivate?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть целая серия классов в *Qt* с постфиксом `Private`.

В чем разница между ними и обычными классами?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это классы для реализации идиомы PIMPL. Pimpl — Pointer to private implementation. Основная идея этого паттерна — это вынести все приватные члены класса и, в некоторых случаях, функционал в приватный класс. Зачем это нужно, можете почитать [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/76248/) и [здесь](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl).

Comment: Зачем это нужно лучше бы подробнее здесь расписать. Сейчас у вас почти ответ-ссылка.